# move ctor of std::string does not work properly?

Tags: c++, exception, move-semantics, stdstring

Why the `msg` is not being modified after the call to `std::move(msg)`?

```
int main()
{
    std::string msg( "Error!" );

    std::cout << "before try-catch: " << msg << '\n';

    try
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument( std::move( msg ) );
    }
    catch ( const std::invalid_argument& ia )
    {
        std::cerr << ia.what( ) << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "after try-catch: " << msg << '\n'; // Here I expect to see an empty msg
                                                     // like this: after try-catch: 

    return 0;
}
```

I want to move `msg` to the ctor of `std::invalid_argument` instead of copying it. I thought that `msg` should be modified and be left in an unspecified but valid state after the call to `std::move`. But this happens:

```
before try-catch: Error!
Error!
after try-catch: Error!
```

Why is this happening? Is the move ctor of `std::string` not being called? Or is this some kind of aggressive compiler optimization despite using -O0 option?

Comment: Does `std::invalid_argument` have an appropriate constructor?

Comment: `std::move` is just a cast to a rvalue, doesn't guarantee that a move constructor is called `std::invalid_argument( const std::string& );` wants a const reference, no constructors are executed here

Comment: @MatG Oh, right. I didn't notice that before. What is the solution for this? Should I write an exception class derived from `std::invalid_argument`  that has a ctor that gets the msg by an rvalue reference? Will this even work?

Comment: Why do you need to move the string? Note that due to the small string optimisation small strings are always copied

Comment: "unspecified but valid" does not mean "empty" and does not mean "anything but the old value", so all is good.

Comment: @Alan Birtles This is just an example. My actual error msg is about 130 chars long. It is passed the 16 byte limit of my compiler's implementation for SSO.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. So is there a way I can be sure that std::move is working as intended? I want to avoid doing an unnecessary copy.

Comment: cppreference [reads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument): *Because copying `std::invalid_argument` is not permitted to throw exceptions, this message is typically stored internally as a separately-allocated reference-counted string. This is also why there is no constructor taking `std::string&&`: it would have to copy the content anyway.*

Comment: @Evg Oh, now I see, there is no way of avoiding the copy in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the only relevant [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument#std::invalid_argument::invalid_argument) of `std::invalid_argument` is:

```
invalid_argument(const std::string& what_arg);
```

Const-ref parameter can bind to anything, including an *xvalue*, which `std::move(msg)` is. `std::move()` itself is just a cast, the real work of moving data out of a string could have been made inside a constructor. But you can't modify an *xvalue* taken by a const-ref. The only option you have is to make a copy, leaving `msg` unmodified.

Cppreference has the following [note](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument#Notes), which explains the absence of a constructor taking `std::string&&`:

> Because copying `std::invalid_argument` is not permitted to throw exceptions, this message is typically stored internally as a separately-allocated reference-counted string. This is also why there is no constructor taking `std::string&&`: it would have to copy the content anyway.

Comment: What I understood from your answer is that a const lvalue reference like `invalid_argument(const std::string& what_arg)` can not get lvalue and xvalue arguments and move them. It can only move arguments of category prvalue. Is this true?

Comment: @digito_evo No. To be able to move from some object, it should be modifiable inside a function (here, inside a constructor). If you pass an argument of any value category by const-ref, you can never move from it. In particular, if you pass prvalue by const-ref, the same rule applies.

Comment: Yes, I see. This whole topic is a bit complicated for me.